# How to detect if google map loaded successfully

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google-maps version 3 in my website.

I ran through problems where the map sometimes does not load, but instead it will be shown as a grey box, and the browser log will be fulled with errors - unfortunately I can't get the log now because the map is working again.

According to some researches, the problem is because of the experimental version I'm using

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=false"></script>
```

Is There a way to find out if the map has been loaded successfully or crashed so I can tell the user to come back soon?

*P.S. I tried the **idle** event, but it has been invoked even when the map crashed.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for the "tilesloaded" event instead. It's the last event to fire when a map (successfully) loads and you are actually showing a map.

If there's no map (e.g. you haven't set the width/height explicitly), this event won't fire even though idle does.

You can use the [Map Events](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-events) example and throttle your connection from within the Network tab to do some tests. [Here](http://jsbin.com/vefucesoci/1/edit?html,output)'s the same example with width/height not set for #map.

Answer (score 3):

I my opinion the best or most certain way is a combination of the `tilesloaded` event and a delayed function to test if a "success-flag" is set.

```
/* flag to indicate google maps is loaded */
googleMapsLoaded = false;

/* listen to the tilesloaded event
   if that is triggered, google maps is loaded successfully for sure */
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
   googleMapsLoaded = true;
   //clear the listener, we only need it once
   google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'tilesloaded');
});

/* a delayed check to see if google maps was ever loaded */
setTimeout(function() {
  if (!googleMapsLoaded) {
     //we have waited 5 secs, google maps is not loaded yet
     alert('google maps is not loaded');
  }    
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In idle event, do following on map object:

Check following:

Use `if (typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object') {...}` to check if it loaded successfully.

And then check `if(map.getCenter) {
var latlng = map.getCenter();
//check here if latlng is object
}`

If any of the "IF" condition fails that means something's wrong.